# Extract string from object and pass it to parent function - Typescript , React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to achieve something rather simple, but i do not know why i am so stuck on it.
I want to send data to an parent function.
This data is only acceptable in a form of a string. But my issue here is that sometimes on click event i may have multiple strings
The final goals is to send them both up

```
setNewFruits('banana' , 'mango')
```

So on click i am getting my object

```
...
  const foundFruits = foundFruitsCategory.fruits
```

***console.log : {name: 'banana', id: 1, color: 'yellow'}***

And the if i want to extract the name only i do :

```
 const foundAndSelectedFruit = foundFruits.map((fruit) => fruit.name)
```

***console.log output:***

```
['banana']
```

But the thing is i want to have the name only as a string `banana` and not as array of strings.
Yes i can say

```
console.log(foundAndSelectedFruit[0])
```

That will give me the `banana` , but the thing is sometimes `onClick` i could have two objects

***console.log output:***

```
[
  {name: 'banana', id: 1, color: 'yellow'}
  {name: 'mango', id: 2, color: 'orange'}
]
```

So the log of `foundAndSelectedFruit` will be

```
['banana','mango']
```

How i can extract them as seperate strings and send them to my update function ?
( The function awaits a string of name )

P.S. I already tried with `forEach` loop , but instead of printing my string it gives me back `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the spread [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)?

```
setNewFruits(...foundAndSelectedFruit)
```

Comment: Yes , the spread operator will return me a string like this `setNewFruits(  banana mango )` . So it is not the answer that i am searching for. I need to send to seperated string to the parent

Comment: If `foundAndSelectedFruit = ['banana','mango']` as I understood. Then the spread operator will do this `setNewFruits('banana', 'mango')`. If you wanted it to be sent individually then you could `foundAndSelectedFruit.forEach(fruit => setNewFruits(fruit))`